# WPF Conditionally Enable KeyBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework, xaml

I have a WPF project in which I am trying to enable/disable keyboard shortcuts based on the state of public property from my viewmodel. Maybe there is a super simple solution to this, but I'm new to WPF and I couldn't find anything from google. Here is my working XAML:

```
 <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="p" Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding OpenEvent}"/>
```

Here is what I would like to do:

```
<KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="p" Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding OpenEvent}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsOnline}"/>
```

Basically, I'm wondering if there is something similar to the "IsEnabled" property of WPF buttons that I can apply to this. I have about 20 different shortcuts that are depending on this variable. I could go into the code behind for each of the 20 commands and add logic, but that seems fairly kludgy and I'm thinking there has to be a better way. I've seen solutions using "CanExecute", but that is for commands of type ICommand and I'm using commands of type RelayCommand.

Comment: hello, are you using `mvvm-light`?

Comment: @dellywheel Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Good framework :) I'll post an example in a sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `mvvm-light` `RelayCommand` CanExecute in your KeyBinding Commands. Heres a simple example where I have blocked the use of the P Key based on `SomeProperty`

MainViewModel.cs

```
private bool someProperty = false;

    public bool SomeProperty
    {
        get { return someProperty = false; }
        set { Set(() => SomeProperty, ref someProperty, value); }
    }

    private RelayCommand someCommand;
    public RelayCommand SomeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return someCommand ??
                new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                //SomeCommand actions
            }, () =>
            {
                //CanExecute
                if (SomeProperty)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            });
        }
    }
```

and the `Binding` on the front end
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="P" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Width="200" Height="35" />
</Grid>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Use the command's CanExecute method on your view-model.

Then you could remove your IsEnabled property within your XAML.